# How to use timedelta with pandas df.query()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I would like to be able to pass in text from a user or file to filter pandas, which seems like query is the best way to handle it. However, I have a datetime index and can't seem to figure out a way to use timedeltas. I know I can filter dates with > or < like

```
query_string = 'index < datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 20, 11, 8, 19, 615268)'
df.query(queryString)
```

and

```
date = datetime.datetime.now()
query_string = 'index < @date'
df.query(queryString)
```

What I want to do is get a relative date range like getting the last 10 seconds of entries

```
date = datetime.now()
query_string = 'index > @date - datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)'
df.query(query_string)
```

This fails, and I can't seem to find a way to do something like filter anything relative to a timestamp. Is there any other way to format it so I can add/subtract a time from a date using df.query()?

Answer (score 1):

Query does not support timedelta (checked in version Pandas 1.0.5). You can work around it using:

```
df[df['index'] >= datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(10, 'S')]
```

Comment: Any idea if this is still true? The 'eval' docs at least mentions datetime in passing: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#technical-minutia-regarding-expression-evaluation